# largest perfect square in octal number system

Tags: sequences-and-series

The largest perfect square of n digits in Decimal number system is 
$$
\left(\left\lceil\sqrt{10^n}\right\rceil-1\right)^2
$$
But what will be the largest perfect square of n digits in octal number system?

Comment: If you know how this expression is constructed, the answer is obvious. And if not, if you just look at it and make a guess, odds are you will be correct. What do _you_ think the expression is?

Comment: I am not able to find..Please help

Comment: I'm telling you to, at the very least, _guess_. If you had to make a single guess, what do you _think_ the answer ought to be? If you have some simple reason for making that guess, then all the better. You're changing from **decimal** to **octal**. What seems like a reasonable change to make?

Comment: pow(ceil(sqrt(pow(7, n))) - 1, 2) .  This is what i have guessed. Is this correct?

Comment: Cool! And have you tested it? Does it find the right squares for, say, $n=1,2$ or $3$?

Comment: It's giving 36 for n = 2 which is wrong because 64 would be the largest perfect square for n = 2. Please help now.

Comment: Excellent. Of course! Note that $64$ is a three-digit number in octal, so you want $49$. But back to the formula, why did you choose $7$? Is there $9$ somewhere in the decimal version?

Comment: pow(ceil(sqrt(pow(8, n))) - 1, 2)  Now is it okay?

Comment: pow(ceil(sqrt(pow(8, n))) - 1, 2)  In this also 49 is coming for n = 2 but 9 is not allowed in octal.

Comment: That looks a lot better. Yes, I suspect that that's the correct version. "9 is not allowed in octal" There is problem here. $49_{10}=61_8$ is still perfect square, and the largest two-digit square in octal.

Comment: But pow(ceil(sqrt(pow(8, n))) - 1, 2) is not giving 61. Should i convert 49 into octal and that will be the final answer

Comment: Yup. That's what I'm saying.